# jQuery parents() with object reference selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parents

I am trying to detect whether a target element is either a child element, or the same element, that I have as an object reference.

I am using the following logic:

```
$("html").on("mousewheel.scroll DOMMouseScroll.scroll",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var $scrollableElement = $(".foo").eq(0);
   var $target = $(e.target);

   if ($target == $scrollableElement
       || $target.parents($scrollableElement).length) {                
        alert("scroll");                    
   }

});
```

However "scroll" is alerted even when scrolling over an element which is neither `.foo` or a child of `.foo`.

In my JsFiddle example, scroll over the `.bar` element, and "scroll" is still alerted:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf3d2/

Why is this? Is it possible to use jQuery object references as the selector of `.parents()`?

Comment: Why do you bind event to html and not to `.foo` ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I wish to prevent scroll unless on `.foo` or a child of `.foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(function () {

    var $scrollableElement = $(".foo").eq(0);
    $("html").on("mousewheel.scroll DOMMouseScroll.scroll", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.closest($scrollableElement).length) {
            console.log("scroll");
        }

    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B6w5t/)

If you have a look at the syntax of [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), it does not take a jQuery object as a parameter. The only allowed syntax is `.parents( [selector ] )`

---

*As @A.Wolff asked why don't bind the event to `.foo` instead*

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B6w5t/2/)